# Regex Pattern for Javascript and validate the same

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a textbox in my MVC application where I will allow text only 012-345-6
pattern.I am new you in regex and never created my own..
I have to validate the same pattern from javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
^(\d{3}\-){2}\d$
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bP0xN0/3)

Comment: `{1}` doesnt make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

To validate `012-345-6` pattern, you can use following `regex`.

```
^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d$
```

You can also use [`^(\d{3}-){2}\d$`](https://regex101.com/r/fI7tI2/1) shorter version.

**Explanation:**

1. `\d`: Matches any digit
2. `{n}`: Matches previous character class `n` exactly number of times
3. `-`: Matches `-` literal
4. `^`: Starts with
5. `$`: Ends with

**Visualization**

[image]

**Demo:**

```js
var regex = /^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d$/;

document.getElementById('myText').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  var value = this.value;

  if (value && regex.test(value)) {
    console.log('if');
    this.classList.add('success');
  } else {
    console.log('else');
    this.classList.remove('success');
  }
}, false);
```

```css
input[type=text] {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.success {
  border: 1px solid green !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myText" />
```

Comment: three digits at the second.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks! Updated

Comment: But it'm the one who posted first, and you don;t need to add `{1}` next to `\d`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks for the `\d`. We both have posted the answer at the same time

Comment: `/^(\d{3}-){2}\d$/.test("123-456-6")` even shorter ;P

Comment: @GottZ Already added in answer. `You can also use ^(\d{3}-){2}\d$ shorter version.
`

Comment: @Tushar oh sorry. i didnt read all answers yet. you are right. oh wait.. its in your answer aswell.. seems like i'm blind. sorry.

Comment: @Tushar I posted 1 min before yopu and your first regex fails to match the above input.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below anchored regex.

```
^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d$
```

- `^` start
- `\d{3}` matches exactly three digit chars.
- `\d` matches a single digit.
- `$` end of the line.